# If $a_n \to 0$ then $(a_1+\cdots+a_n)/n \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Where $a_n \in C$, intuitively I think this must be true as if are taking an average of almost all arbitrarily small numbers then the average will be arbitrarily small.

let $\epsilon>0, \exists N:|a_n|<\epsilon, \forall n>N$
$$ |(a_1+\cdots+a_n)/n|<\epsilon$$
$$|a_1+\cdots+a_N+\cdots+a_n|<e n$$ 
I know this is wrong but this was what I was thinking
$$|a_1+\cdots+a_N|+(n-N)\epsilon<en$$
Could I have a rough hint on a how to better estimate the value of $ |(a_1+\cdots+a_n)/n|$

Comment: No the way you start looks exactly right... not sure why you put the $n$ on the RHS. The first term tends to zero and the second term is less than epsilon so it can always be less than epsilon for sufficiently large $n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists an integer $N_0$ such that
$$|a_k|<\frac\varepsilon 2 \quad\forall k>N_0.$$
So, if $n>N_0$, we have
\begin{align}
\biggl|\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{N_0}+\dots +a_n}n\biggr|&\le\frac{|a_1+\dots+a_{N_0}|}n+\frac{|a_{N_0+1}|}n+\dots+\frac{|a_{n}|}n \\[0.5ex]
 &< \frac{|a_1+\dots+a_{N_0}|}n+\frac{n-N_0}n\frac\varepsilon 2 <\frac{|a_1+\dots+a_{N_0}|}n +\frac\varepsilon 2 
\end{align}
Now $|a_1+\dots+a_{N_0}|$ does not depend on $n$, so it tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, and there exist an integer $N_1$ such that
$$\frac{|a_1+\dots+a_{N_0}|}n<\frac\varepsilon 2 \quad\forall n>N_1. $$
Now set $N=\max(N_0,N_1)$. For all  $n>N$, both inequalities are satisfied, so
$$\biggl|\frac{a_1+\dots+a_N+\dots a_n}n\biggr|<\frac\varepsilon 2+\frac\varepsilon 2=\varepsilon.$$